# How to pass java object to lua then pass it back

Tags: java, lua, luajava

I'm using luajava.
want to do like this

```lua
local result = luajava.newInstance("org.foo.Bar",javaobj);
```

Then i found i can't use javaobj as a argument

too many method needs a javaobj as argument

but i can't use complex argument in lua

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.